# Provide Entity Framework hints about how / what order to cascade delete

Tags: entity-framework

I am doing a Code-first EF approach except for the fact that I am managing the database (for schema change issues that I believe still exist in code-first). I have the following tables / model objects (eliding several parameters, etc) :

```
class A {
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
public virtual List<B> BList {get;set;}
public virtual List<C> CList  {get;set;}
}

class B {
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("A"), Required]
public int AId {get; set;}
public virtual A parent {get;set;}
public virtual List<D> DList {get;set;}
}

class C {
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("A"), Required]
public int AId {get;set;}
[ForeignKey("someD"), Required]
public int someDId {get;set}
public virtual D someD
}

class D {
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("B"), Required]
public int BId {get;set;}
public string data {get;set;}
}
```

There's more to it than that, but the idea is that from a parent object A, I can navigate to a D along two different relationships. The Cascade delete relationships in the database are set up such that A->B, A->C, and B->D are cascades; C->D is 'no action'.

Therefore, when I go to delete an A (DbSet.Remove(a); SaveChanges(); etc ) EF needs to delete the C branch first, so that it can later delete the D's and not violate the FK constraint C->D. However, it appears to be choosing the other path, as the delete throws an exception about said constraint being violated. Is there a way for me to provide a hint (attribute or otherwise) to EF to tell it something else about these relationships so it can delete things in the right order?

**edit** Added more clarity to the approach in the code; Also, this thought occurs to me: I'm not explicitly capturing the relationship from C->D on D's end - that is, there is no navigation property on D that points to C; because C is a part of a Table-per-type scheme and not all D's point to a good collection of C's base class. Do I need to have some kind of navigation property in D back to C for EF to understand what I want?

Comment: Do you have any fluent mapping for your entities?

Comment: No, I don't. I'm making my constraints manually. I'll edit my question so that the sketches more fully represent the classes.